# Comparing two large file using Linux?

Tags: linux, compare, unique

**file1:**

```
asd
1
asdfg
2
asdasd
```

**file 2:**

```
asd
asdfg
asdasd
123
12333
```

expected result

```
1
2
```

current result

```
1
2
123
12333
```

awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{lines[$0];next} !($0 in lines)' file1 file2

awk 'NR==FNR{lines[$0];next} !($0 in lines)' file1 file2
```

as shown above the current result is all the duplicate data.

Comment: The current result is not the duplicate data, but the differences. Why do you expect something different from the diff of the two files?

Comment: @msfoster im expecting data from file1 that was not in file2.
but im getting all the diff from both file1 and file2

Comment: Is the spaces really newlines? 
It works as you expect if each word in the files is on separate lines and you  switch the fileparameters: file2 file1

Comment: No Sorry it should be newline but it did work that way when i post it here

Answer (score 0):

```
comm -23 --nocheck-order file1 file2
```